# CoreData: Reload Data Before returning to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I know core data is very much tied to the UITableViewController, however I have an app that has two pages which you can update data on, it would be great if I could see updated values reflected in the relevant labels of each page without having to return to the UITableViewController and using tableView.reloadData(). Is there a way to achieve this? 
Thanks

EDIT: I've added a diagram which I hopes makes my question a little clearer. I'd like to make updates to the managed object in view D, which I can confirm (via println) is already working as expected, however when I poptoViewController C, nothing has changed and I'm seeing outdated information. Only when I return to A, the tableview, do the changes to the object become apparent in the UI. So is there a way I can reload the object on view C without having to go back to A?

EDIT #2: After reading the responses below (thanks!), I think that my question boils down to **How can I implement the functionality of NSFetchedResultsController on a ViewController that does not have a UITableView?**

[image]

Comment: Why is using `reloadData()` a problem? Can you explain a bit more what your app looks like?

Comment: The data is contained in the "data source", which is managed by your UITableViewDataSource object.  The fact that it may or may not be "backed" by CoreData is irrelevant.  When the "data source" changes then `reloadData` (or one of the other `reload...` operations) must be issued for the TableView to know the data has changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` gives you this functionality almost for free. Implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and set the `frc.delegate = self`. When changes are made in Core Data, the appropriate delegate methods will be called

The code below is boilerplate from the iOS Master/Detail Core Data template that Xcode sets you up with. To get a copy of all of this, go File -> New -> Project -> Master-Detail Application -> then check "Use Core Data".

**Swift**

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Update:
            self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
        case .Move:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        default:
            return;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrt to your question:

> How can I implement the functionality of NSFetchedResultsController on
>   a ViewController that does not have a UITableView?

Your ViewController should subscribe to the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification. Look at the notification's userInfo and  process the keys `updatedObjects`, `insertedObjects` and `deletedObjects`. 
When any of the objects is of interest to your ViewController then update the view.

Here [is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154923/529243)